# How to get Picklist Values from Apex controller in lightning component dynamically..?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

how to get picklist values from schema in lightning component can anyone help me?
i have a picklist called "status" and i want to fetch the values from controller rather than hardcoding in component itself..

thanks 
Ruhulla

Comment: Do any of these [questions and answers](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Blightning-components%5D+picklist) help?

Answer (score 2):

You can make Apex Describe call in your controller to prepare List of strings containing picklist values. eg. - picklistValues is the collection.

On your Lightning Component- Below mentioned code can be used to refer it dynamically.

```
<select id="selection" class="slds-select">
 <option value="None">--None--</option>
 <aura:iteration items="{!picklistValues}" var="p">
    <option value="{!p}">{!p}</option>
 </aura:iteration>
</select>
```

Let me know in case of any more details or help.

-SK

Comment: Hi, can u please provide a controller code? thanks

Comment: You can refer [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2008/12/using-the-metadata-api-to-retrieve-picklist-values.html) for your reference. In your case, better if you prepare collection of strings instead of List<selectOptions>